# Is there a way to solve this method calling error?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm started using classes not so long ago and I'm struggling a lot with the following issue.

Once I click the button to change label from 0 to 1, it gives me this error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\patht\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
TypeError: increment1() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Code:

```
#modules
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class Item_Set:
    def __init__(self, root, text1, text2, text3,x,y, img, img2, img3):
        self.canvas = Canvas(width=400, height=130)
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        #
        self.widget1 = Label(root, text=text1, font=("Courier", 10))
        self.image1 = PhotoImage(file=img)
        self.button_i = Button(root, text="+", fg="blue",font=("Courier", 6), command=Item_Set.increment1)
        self.button_d = Button(root, text="-", fg="red",font=("Courier", 6))
        self.num1 = 0
        self.widget_num1 = Label(root, text=str(self.num1), font=("Courier", 12))
        #
        self.widget2 = Label(root, text=text2, font=("Courier", 10))
        self.image2 = PhotoImage(file=img2)
        self.button_i2 = Button(root, text="+", fg="blue",font=("Courier", 6))
        self.button_d2 = Button(root, text="-", fg="red",font=("Courier", 6))
        self.num2 = 0
        self.widget_num2 = Label(root, text=str(self.num2), font=("Courier", 12))
        #
        self.widget3 = Label(root, text=text3, font=("Courier", 10))
        self.image3 = PhotoImage(file=img3)
        self.button_i3 = Button(root, text="+", fg="blue",font=("Courier", 6))
        self.button_d3 = Button(root, text="-", fg="red",font=("Courier", 6))
        self.num3 = 0
        self.widget_num3 = Label(root, text=str(self.num3), font=("Courier", 12))

    def start(self):
        self.canvas.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
        #
        self.canvas.create_window(self.x, self.y, window=self.widget1)
        self.canvas.create_image(self.x, self.y+34, image=self.image1)
        self.canvas.create_window(self.x+15, self.y+65, window=self.button_i)
        self.canvas.create_window(self.x-22, self.y+65, window=self.button_d)
        self.canvas.create_window(self.x-2, self.y+65, window=self.widget_num1)
        #
        self.canvas.create_window(self.x + 150, self.y, window=self.widget2)
        self.canvas.create_image(self.x+150, self.y+34, image=self.image2)
        self.canvas.create_window(self.x+165, self.y+65, window=self.button_i2)
        self.canvas.create_window(self.x+128, self.y+65, window=self.button_d2)
        self.canvas.create_window(self.x+148, self.y+65, window=self.widget_num2)
        #
        self.canvas.create_window(self.x + 300, self.y, window=self.widget3)
        self.canvas.create_image(self.x+300, self.y+34, image=self.image3)
        self.canvas.create_window(self.x+315, self.y+65, window=self.button_i3)
        self.canvas.create_window(self.x+278, self.y+65, window=self.button_d3)
        self.canvas.create_window(self.x+298, self.y+65, window=self.widget_num3)

    def increment1(self):
        self.num1 += 1
        self.widget_num1.config(text=str(self.num1))


root = Tk()
root.title('7 Days to die->Items')
item_set_1 = Item_Set(root,'bullet', 'blueberries', 'eggs',40,30, 'img1.png', 'img2.png','img3.png')
item_set_1.start()
item_set_2 = Item_Set(root,'bullet', 'blueberries', 'eggs',40,30, 'img1.png', 'img2.png','img3.png')
item_set_2.start()
item_set_3 = Item_Set(root,'bullet', 'blueberries', 'eggs',40,30, 'img1.png', 'img2.png','img3.png')
item_set_3.start()
root.mainloop()
```

Note: I've researched, but I can't find the answer.

Comment: please format your code

Comment: `command=Item_Set.increment1` → `command=self.increment1`

Answer (score 2):

It's quite straight-forward. Change

```
self.button_i = Button(root, text="+", fg="blue",font=("Courier", 6), command=Item_Set.increment1)
```

to

```
self.button_i = Button(root, text="+", fg="blue",font=("Courier", 6), command=self.increment1)
```

Take a look at class and objects in Python, and you can understand what `self` here means.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was really struggling with classes.